# Programatically ignore some of the attributes of json in Logback?

Tags: json, logging, logback, slf4j

How I can remove some of the attributes of json logging by logaback programatically?

```json
    {
     "time":"2022-06-11T19:50:38.218+05:30",
     "version":"1",
     "message":"This is a normal log statement",
     "logger_name":"NewLogger.App",
     "thread_name":"main",
     "level":"INFO",
     "level_value":20000,
     "myid":"1234"
    }
```

Comment: could you be more specific, how do you generate this log file?

Comment: I want to remove/modify the default attributes of the json logging result programatically.How can I do that?